# Why can't I set view controllers in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to populate a page view controller with 5 events that I am pulling from an API. The idea is that the user can page through the top 5 latest events and click on them to see more details about the event. The issue I am running into is that once I get the events I want to reload the view controller for the page view controller but when I try setting up the view controllers I get an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I set a property observer for my array of events so that once it's set I reload the view controllers. This is how my class looks like:

```swift
class EventPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

var eventViewControllers = [EventViewController]()

var events: [Event] = []{
    didSet {
        self.reloadViewControllers()
    }
}


func reloadViewControllers(){

    self.dataSource = nil
    self.dataSource = self
    // Get top 5 events
    let topFiveEvents = Array(events.prefix(5))
    print(self.events.count)
    self.eventViewControllers.removeAll()
    print(eventViewControllers.count)

    // Set up view controllers
    for event in topFiveEvents{
        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "event") as? EventViewController{
            print(event.title)
            // Just this line alone is what crashes the app
            controller.eventTitle.text = event.title
            self.eventViewControllers.append(controller)
        }
    }

    if self.eventViewControllers.count != 0 {
        let first = [self.eventViewControllers[0]]
        self.setViewControllers(first, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date()).rfc3339String
    let params = ["maxResults": "250",
                  "singleEvents": "true",
                  "timeMin": timeMin]
    NetworkManager.events(forPark: .all, withParameters: params, query: nil) { (events, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.events = events
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    for subView in self.view.subviews {
        if subView is UIScrollView {
            subView.frame = self.view.bounds
        } else if subView is UIPageControl {
            let pageControl = subView as! UIPageControl
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.15, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.15, blue:0.29, alpha:0.30)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: subView)


        }
    }
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}



}
```

If I don't set anything in the view controller then I get the page view controller to show view controllers with static information. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your page view controller is trying to manipulate it's child view controllers' views directly. Don't do that.

This line:

```
controller.eventTitle.text = event.title
```

Is likely the cause, assuming that `eventTitle` is an outlet.

Instead of doing that, add a string property to your child view controllers:

```
public var eventTitleString: String
```

And then set that instead:

```
controller.eventTitleString = event.title
```

And in your child view controller, add code to copy that value into your field:

```
func viewWillAppear(_: animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  eventTitle.text = eventTitleString
}
```

@MrSaturn suggests calling `controller.loadViewIfNeeded()`, which would likely fix your crash, but it's bad practice. You should treat a view controllers' views as private, and never try to manipulate them from outside. Instead add a public property or function that updates your view controller's views directly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that manipulating the child view controllers views was bad practice but your solution worked.

Comment: The principle of "encapsulation" is a fundamental one of object-oriented design. As you design your objects, think about a public "contract" for the services your object provides to other objects. That part should be exposed  and available for other objects to use. Anything else should be private, and off limits outside of the object itself. That way objects are not sensitive to the implementation details of other objects. As long as their public interfaces stay stable, the internals can change in ways large or small and everything still works.

Comment: If you create a view controller that gathers input from the user and reports it to another view controller, that view controller should be free to switch to using a different type of control, or displaying information to the user, in any way it wants. All it should be required to do is to have the same properties and methods. When another object manipulates your view controller's views directly, you lock the view controller into always implementing it's views the same way.